# By the time..., was/had been

Tags: past-tense, future-tense

Could someone tell me what's the difference between:

> By the time we got here, the place **was** barricaded.
>
> By the time we got here, the place **had been** barricaded.

The same question about these examples:

> By the time we get there, the supermarket **will be** closed.
>
> By the time we get there, the supermarket **will have been** closed.

For some reason, it seems a little confusing to me, as I'm not a native speaker. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It terms of conveying meaning there's no difference; the same picture is conveyed, a complete barricade or a closed supermarket.

In analysing how the meaning is conveyed one approach has the focus on the state of an object and one focuses on the action that changes the state.

> the supermarket is closed

We look at a supermarket and see that the doors are locked and the lights are off.

> the supermarket has been closed

here we focus on the activity of closing, a person has locked the door and turned out the lights.

Choosing between such options seems to me to be mostly a matter of style. In your particular example

> the supermarket will have been closed

does feel a little ungainly, **will be** seems easier and give a greater sense of urgency.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible they mean the same thing, but it's also possible they don't.

---

> 1. By the time we got here, the place **was** barricaded.

This means that when we got there, there were barricades in place.

---

> 2. By the time we got here, the place **had been** barricaded.

All this means is that when we got there, the place had been barricaded at some point before. It may or may not *still* have been barricaded when we arrived.

For instance, both of the following could be added:

> 2. a) By the time we got there, the place had been barricaded [*three times already, but each time the obstacles had been removed. **It's current state was free of barricades**].*
>
> 2. b) By the time we got there, the place had been barricaded [*three times already, but the first two times, the obstacles had been removed. **However, after the third time, they were still in place**].*

---

Without additional context or clarification, *had been* doesn't give a definite statement about the current situation (with respect to the time period being described).

So, the two sentence *might* mean the same thing—or they might not.

The same analysis applies to the second set of sentences. ***Will have been*** *closed* doesn't necessarily mean that it will ***still*** be closed when we get there. Only that it will have been closed at least once at some point.